# SQL matching - How to pull all values for each unique value in one column and compare

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a SQL table that looks like the one seen below. It has about 4000 observations. Below is an excerpt. I need help in pulling all distinct values ( project names) , grouping them according to project name, and pulling the 2 most recent dates for each project name, comparing the status value, and returning a " y " in a new column if certain parameters are met. i.e. ( if for project name 18362, the status values of the 2 most recent report dates are both equal to 1, return a yes)

```
Report Date  Project Name    Status value
3/21/2016   18362                 1
3/14/2016   18355                 1
6/8/2015    18342                 2
4/20/2015   11234                 1
2/15/2015   17893                 2
```

Comment: This reminds me of the old Johnny Rivers song, where he sang, "they're giving you a number, and taking away your name" (IOW, how is it that Project Name is a number?)

Comment: Project Name was originally a number plus a text string, I however deleted the text string for the sake of this example. No need to put all information out on the internet.

Comment: Typically I would do this through R or python. A simple loop would suffice. I am not sure however how to do this through SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can do this with a rather nasty correlated subquery:

```
update t
    set status = (select iif(count(*) = 2, 'yes', 'no')
                  from t as t2
                  where t2.projectname = t.projectname and
                        t2.status = 1 and
                        t2.reportdate in (select top 2 t3.reportdate
                                          from t as t3
                                          where t3.projectname = t2.projectname 
                                          order by t3.reportdate desc
                                         )
                 );
```

Comment: Ok great. Thanks. This works. I will try and find a cleaner way in the future but this should do it.